# How to assign an attribute to a variable stored in a data.table

Tags: r, data.table

What is an efficient way to modify a variable or a series of variables in a `data.table` to add or change attributes?  For example, the R `Hmisc` package `label` function will add a `label` attribute to a variable, and make it class `"labelled"` so that [. and other operators will preserve the label (the package defines `[.labelled`.  Likewise there is `Hmisc::units` to specify units of measurement.  I typically add `label`s and `units` by using for example

```
label(age) <- 'Age at study entry'               # or:
label(mydataframe$age) <- 'Age at study entry'   # or:
mydataframe <- upData(mydataframe, labels=c(age='Age at study entry'), units='year')
```

`data.table` is correctly preserving attributes for simple operations:

```
require(Hmisc)
x1 <- runif(10)
label(x1) <- 'This is a label'
units(x1) <- 'xunits'
x2 <- rnorm(10)
d <- data.table(x1, x2)
label(d$x1)      # label there
label(d[,'x1'])  # label gone
label(d[1:3,]$x1)# label there
label(d[,x1])    # label there
units(d[1:2,x1]) # yes
```

so the primary question is how to insert attributes into an already existing `data.table` object with a minimum of memory use/execution time.

Comment: What is an example of a typical data.table operation where your labels are  not preserved?

Comment: Great question and I should have addressed that.  Will edit top post now.

Comment: Note that `d[,'x1']` returns a `data.table` and  `d[1:3,]$x1` returns the vector... the actual label attribute follows the vector.

Comment: you can subsribe to this issue to be informed about the feature: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/623 also you may want to upvote it

Answer (score 3):

#### Setting variable attributes (including labels) in data.table:

To easily and efficiently (by reference) set the label you can use: `setattr()`.

Example:

```
library(data.table)
iDT <- data.table(iris)

setattr(iDT$Species, "label", "Know the species")
attributes(iDT$Species)

# $levels
# [1] "setosa"     "versicolor" "virginica" 
# 
# $class
# [1] "factor"
# 
# $label
# [1] "Know the species"
```

Comment: Wonderful.  How would I use the full capabilities of `Hmisc::label` such that I can provide multiple attributes at once (`label` and `units` plus possibly `class`) so that the attributes will survive subsetting?

Comment: I guess you could try something like `setattr(iDT$Species, "class", c("factor", "labelled"))`? In general I am not convinced attributes are the best place to keep metadata.

Comment: @FrankHarrell Your question is a bit unclear. data.table preserves attributes. I'd suggest you provide a simple `setlabel` function modeled after this answer for use with data.table (but it could be used elsewhere too).

Comment: I will try that.  It would be nice if a compact syntax would work, i.e., one that looks more like `setkey()`.  I've wondered too whether there is a better place to store metadata, but I've never found one that is safe for subsetting and that doesn't require a bit more bookkeeping.

Comment: I'm going to modify the R `Hmisc` package `upData` function to do `setattr` in a loop over the variables which are being given `labels` or `units`.  `data.table` is blazing fast at doing this.

Comment: I found in updating `upData` that it was already very fast except in `NA` checking and it used `attr(mydata$x, 'something') <- 'something'` which is very much slower than `x <- mydata$x; attr(x,'something') <- 'something'; mydata$x <- x`.